# Why is Mars has it name Mangal (auspicious)?

Tags: astrology

मङ्गल means auspicious but Mangal is considered as papa graha in astrology. Why is that, does anybody know the explanation?

Comment: Papa does not mean sinner in astrology, rather an intense planet. By your logic, even Sun is malefic in astrology, yet Hindus worship Sun everyday and life is not possible on earth without Sun. Mars, Sun, Saturn are malefic because they are real world, daytime, hot masculine, work environment, energy draining planets while Moon, Jupiter and Venus are benefic because these are nighttime, home, cold feminine nourishing planets, while Mercury is neutral.

Comment: Do not mess diffrent topics into one. Papa means evil in sanskrit and Surya considered as krura graha but not papa. The fact that Hindus worship the Surya every day has nothing to do with the topic